# How can I get this Python code to replace all the items in lst1 that appear in the string email_one with the corresponding index element in lst2?

Tags: python, string, list

Right now, it only replaces the last lst1 item with the corresponding lst2 item ("Famine" with "Hunger") but not the first ('learning algorithms', with 'analysis technology').

```
lst1 = ['learning algorithms', 'Famine']
lst2 = ['analysis technology', 'Hunger']

for i in range(len(lst1)):
    if lst1[i] in email_one:
      new_email = email_one.replace(lst1[i], lst2[i])

print(new_email)
```

**And the result of print(new_email)**:

Progress is going great!

We have made great strides in the last month improving the learning algorithms that the system has been using to acquire information.

Every month we come closer to achieving our goal of making the world a better place. Hunger, plague, war, and poverty are all conquerable with the power of our system!

Till next month,

Answer (score 0):

Every time you make an update, you're erasing the previous updates you made because you're changing the original string (email_one), not the updated version (new_email) and reassigning new_email to email_one + latest change. Try this:

```
new_email = email_one
for i in range(len(lst1)):
    if lst1[i] in email_one:
        new_email = new_email.replace(lst1[i], lst2[i])
```

This way, you keep the changes you make in new_email.

Comment: Got it, that was it. Thanks!